# how can i close fancy box it self, after submitting details?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using registration.php file at in fancy box ifarme class as:

```
<li><a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="registration.php"><img src="registration.jpg"/></a></li>
```

when I click on registration.jpg a form will be pop-up, after entering details in that, I'll click on submit, if the details submits successfully, the pop-up(fancy box) should close itself, after showing that " your details submitted successfully "

thanks ina advance..

Answer (score 0):

Right at the bottom of the API docs for fancybox there are a list of methods you can use - one of which is close.

```
$.fancybox.close
```

> Hides FancyBox
>
> Within an iframe use - parent.$.fancybox.close();

You can bind this method to either a click event or a callback to execute on success of your form submitting.

E.g

```
$(".form-submit").on("click", function () {
    /* Use a conditional to check if form submits successfully */
    if (formSubmit) {
        parent.$.fancybox.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your parent page (from where you call the `registration.php` file) you could create a custom *function* (e.g. `afterSubmit()`) like

```
function afterSubmit() {
    jQuery.fancybox("Form successfully submitted");
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery.fancybox.close();
    }, 2000);
}
```

This function will open a new fancybox with the message you want (and will close any previous opened fancybox) and it will auto-close itself after 2 seconds (or whatever time you want to set)

Then, validate the form submission in `registration.php` file and when is successful, call the custom function in the parent page like :

```
parent.afterSubmit();
```

**Notice** both pages must be within the same domain.